# How to tell remote machines not to start separate roscores when using roslaunch? (Fuerte regression?)

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-master-uri, ros-fuerte, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

My goal is to start nodes on different machines using roslaunch while all the nodes should communicate to one master. This worked in electric. In fuerte the same process starts now a master for each machine. I guess something has changed, what do I need to do to fix it?

I created a sample launchfile that looks like this:

```
<launch>
    <machine name="m3" address="marvin-3" default="true"/>
    <machine name="m4" address="marvin-4" default="true"/>

    <group >
        <node name="m" pkg="turtlesim" type="mimic" respawn="false" machine="m4"/>
        <node name="t" pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" respawn="false" machine="m3"/>
    </group>
</launch>
```

I start my launch-script in the following way:

```
user@marvin-3:~$ export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://marvin-3:11311"
user@marvin-3:~$ roslaunch myLaunch.launch
```

The output I get looks like this:

```
user@marvin-3:~$ roslaunch myLaunch.launch 
... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/827ebf04-b705-11e1-85a7-bcaec524ca66/roslaunch-marvin-3-23516.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://marvin-3:51304/
remote[marvin-4-0] starting roslaunch
remote[marvin-4-0]: creating ssh connection to marvin-4:22
launching remote roslaunch child with command: [/opt/ros/fuerte/env.sh roslaunch -c marvin-4-0 -u http://marvin-3:51304/ --run_id 827ebf04-b705-11e1-85a7-bcaec524ca66]
remote[marvin-4-0]: ssh connection created

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

MACHINES
 * m3
 * m4

NODES
  /
    t (turtlesim/turtlesim_node)
    m (turtlesim/mimic)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [23535]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://marvin-3:11311

setting /run_id to 827ebf04-b705-11e1-85a7-bcaec524ca66
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [23548]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[t-2]: started with pid [23560]
[marvin-4-0]: launching nodes...
[marvin-4-0]: auto-starting new master
[marvin-4-0]: process[master]: started with pid [27764]
[marvin-4-0]: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
[marvin-4-0]: setting /run_id to 827ebf04-b705-11e1-85a7-bcaec524ca66
[marvin-4-0]: process[m-1]: started with pid [27778]
[marvin-4-0]: ... done launching nodes
```

In the line

```
[marvin-4-0]: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

things are starting to go wrong. This should be rather set to marvin-3 (that is why I set ROS_MASTER_URI before running the launch script).

I realize (and confirmed) that I can set the ROS_MASTER_URI using a custom env-loader on my target machine. But that seems to be very complicated. This also leads to an explosion of the number of env-scripts needed.

I tried to look into the tutorial [Roslaunch tips for larger projects](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects). But that seems outdated.

Does someone have a better solution for me here?

Dirk

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36600/how-to-tell-remote-machines-not-to-start-separate-roscores-when-using-roslaunch?-(fuerte-regression?)/) by [dk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1043/dk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 176 on 2012-06-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems this is actually a bug which has been fixed in svn and which will be pushed out with the next version of ros-fuerte-ros-comm (1.8.14). See here https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3990

---

Originally posted by [dk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1043/dk/) with karma: 176 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is very old but I just had a similar struggle with the setup myself (on melodic) and thought I would share my problem and solution. On my master I had **ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311** and on my remote I used **ROS_MASTER_URI=http:/ctrl-pc:11311**. This is fine for normal operation but if you use roslaunch with machine to run nodes on your remote device it will overwrite **ROS_MASTER_URI** on your remote pc with the one set on your master (the one you execute your launch file from), which ends up to be localhost, thus roslaunch will start a new roscore. Using **export ROS_MASTER_URI=http:/ctrl-pc:11311** on both machines solved the problem.
**Tl;dr:** do not use localhost in **ROS_MASTER_URI**.

---

Originally posted by [TomPe](https://answers.ros.org/users/51293/tompe/) with karma: 11 on 2020-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1